# Eliminate blood vessels from retinal image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to eliminate the blood vessels from a retinal image and remain the exudates using edge detection technique 'Kirsch's Templates' but still some parts of the unwanted blood vessels and optic disc 'the circular shape' on the left side of the image remain. I wonder if there is a better solution to perfectly eliminate these or adding some other techniques?

**Main :**

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

%Read Input Retina Image
inImg = imread('image013b.png');
dim = ndims(inImg);
if(dim == 3)
    %Input is a color image
    inImg = rgb2gray(inImg);
end

%Extract Blood Vessels
Threshold = 6;
bloodVessels = VesselExtract(inImg, Threshold);

%Output Blood Vessels image

figure;
subplot(121);imshow(inImg);title('Input Image');
subplot(122);imshow(bloodVessels);title('Extracted Blood Vessels');
```

**VesselExtract.m:**

```
function bloodVessels = VesselExtract(inImg, threshold)

%Kirsch's Templates
h1=[5 -3 -3;
    5  0 -3;
    5 -3 -3]/15;
h2=[-3 -3 5;
    -3  0 5;
    -3 -3 5]/15;
h3=[-3 -3 -3;
     5  0 -3;
     5  5 -3]/15;
h4=[-3  5  5;
    -3  0  5;
    -3 -3 -3]/15;
h5=[-3 -3 -3;
    -3  0 -3;
     5  5  5]/15;
h6=[ 5  5  5;
    -3  0 -3;
    -3 -3 -3]/15;
h7=[-3 -3 -3;
    -3  0  5;
    -3  5  5]/15;
h8=[ 5  5 -3;
     5  0 -3;
    -3 -3 -3]/15;

%Spatial Filtering by Kirsch's Templates
t1=filter2(h1,inImg);
t2=filter2(h2,inImg);
t3=filter2(h3,inImg);
t4=filter2(h4,inImg);
t5=filter2(h5,inImg);
t6=filter2(h6,inImg);
t7=filter2(h7,inImg);
t8=filter2(h8,inImg);

s=size(inImg);
bloodVessels=zeros(s(1),s(2));
temp=zeros(1,8);

%

for i=1:s(1)
    for j=1:s(2)
        temp(1)=t1(i,j);temp(2)=t2(i,j);temp(3)=t3(i,j);temp(4)=t4(i,j);
        temp(5)=t5(i,j);temp(6)=t6(i,j);temp(7)=t7(i,j);temp(8)=t8(i,j);
        if(max(temp)>threshold)
            bloodVessels(i,j)=max(temp);
        end
    end
end
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem, but I'd [check the type](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) of `inImg`. It may be a `uint8` type (unsigned 8-bit integer, as many images are), but your processing may require it to be a `double` (floating point) to get the desired results.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem to change the data type it is more related to the threshold value but, I need an additional technique to delete the left side circle (the optic disc) and the blood vessels before the exudates detection. As exudates must be the last remaining white pixels in the image.

Comment: To eliminate curvilinear features, you'd best look into curve tracking or ridge finding methods. You might get some ideas from here: http://mriquestions.com/dti-tensor-imaging.html  Also, Stroke Width Transform to identify written characters could be adapted to identifying curves of (relatively) fixed width such as the blood vessels; even a  general understanding of SWT could lead you to some new ideas to test. Good luck!